# Get the Default GCP Project ID with a Cloud SDK CLI One-Liner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I’m looking for a `gcloud` one-liner to get the default project ID (`$GCP_PROJECT_ID`).

The `list` command gives me:

```shell
gcloud config list core/project

#=>

[core]
project = $GCP_PROJECT_ID

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

While I only want the following output:

```shell
gcloud . . .

#=>

$GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `--format` flag with `gcloud`:

```shell
gcloud config list --format 'value(core.project)' 2>/dev/null
```

The `--format` flag is available on all commands and gives you full control over what is printed, and how it is formatted.

You can see this help page for full info:

```shell
gcloud topic formats
```

Comment: Note that this prints some extra information to standard error, but the actual value is printed to standard out. I was able to capture the project ID into an environment variable with `export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config list --format 'value(core.project)')`

Comment: It doesn't print anything to stderr for me - maybe that's changed? Google Cloud SDK version 227

Answer (score 75):

Thanks to comment from Tim Swast above, I was able to use:

```shell
export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)
```

to get the project ID.  Running the `get-value` command prints the following:

```shell
gcloud config get-value project


#=>

Your active configuration is: [default]

$PROJECT_ID
```

You can also run:

```shell
gcloud config get-value project 2> /dev/null
```

to just print `$PROJECT_ID` and suppress other warnings/errors.

Comment: You can also run `gcloud config get-value project 2> /dev/null` to print just the project ID and suppress other warnings/errors. Updated the answer.

Comment: This is the best way I've found too, but it's quite slow because `gcloud` is just slow to start up. 2-3 sec per call, so (for instance) too slow to put in a shell prompt function. Is there any way that's faster?

Comment: This is the solution I used too

Answer (score 37):

With Google Cloud SDK 266.0.0 you can use following command:

```
gcloud config get-value project
```

Answer (score 7):

From Cloud Shell or any machine where Cloud SDK is installed, we can use:

```
echo $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID
```

And as shown in the below screenshot.

[image: A command to get GCP project ID]

I got a question about how to set the environment variable $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID; here are the steps:

- If the URL has the variable `project` and is set to some project id, then the environment variable $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID usually will be set to the project id.
- If the variable `project` is not set in the URL, we can choose the project from the Combobox (besides the title `Google Cloud Platform`) which will set the variable `project` in the URL. We may need to restart the Cloud Shell or refresh the entire web page to set the environment variable $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID.
- Otherwise, if the environment variable $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID is not set, we can set it by the command shown below where we replace PROJECT_ID with the actual project id.

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

- All these are shown in the below figure.

[image: How to set the environment variable $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID]

Comment: The environment variable `$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID` does **not** _seem_ to be set by default on a machine with the Cloud SDK installed.  Would you be able to update this answer with some supporting information about `$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: Hello @Mike, I have updated the answer. I hope this may help.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the gcloud command you specified, but will return you the currently configured project:

```
gcloud info |tr -d '[]' | awk '/project:/ {print $2}'
```

Works for account, zone and region as well.

Answer (score 1):

Direct and easy way to get the default `$PROJECT_ID` is answered above.

In case you would like to get `$PROJECT_ID` from the `info` command, here is a way to do it:

```shell
gcloud info --format=flattened | awk '/config.project/ {print $2}'
```

or:

```shell
gcloud info --format=json | jq '.config.project' | tr -d '"'
```

Just run:

```shell
gcloud info --format={flattened|json}
```

to see the output, then use `awk`, `jq` or similar tools to grab what you need.