# How do I get the organization ID of my current project in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-resource-manager

I would like to know the organization ID of my current project in GCP.

`gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID` will show the `parent` which can be the organization, but if the parent is a `folder`, the organization ID does not appear.

I could recurse up the parent hierarchy of the folders using `gcloud resource-manager folders describe FOLDER_ID`, but that is a hassle. It is also impossible if I do not have organization-level permissions.

Yet I do have access to organization IDs: `gcloud organizations list` shows several organizations, though not their mapping to projects.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599414/gcloud-command-line-get-default-project-id

Comment: No, that is about projects; I am asking about organizations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the below gcloud command in cloud shell.

```
gcloud projects get-ancestors {projectId}
```

This should give the output as below.

```
ID                      TYPE
Your-project-ID         project
123456789012            folder
567890123456            organization
```

Answer (score 4):

If we read [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy) we find that your organization is the root of the ancestor tree of your current project.

We also find that there is an API that can be called to retrieve the ancestry chain from a given project upwards.  This means that we can retrieve the organization id of your project using that API.

The API is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getAncestry).

It has the high level REST format of:

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}:getAncestry
```

A possible command might be:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer \"$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)\"" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
             https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<MY_PROJECT>:getAncestry
```

Comment: That works! But please explain how to do direct REST calls. Can I do it with my local `gcloud` environment and without generating a credentials JSON? (With the credentials JSON  I'd do `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<JSON credentials file path>` followed by `curl -X POST 
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) 
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<MY PROJECT>:getAncestry`)

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question of how to make a REST call with your post using the "curl" command?

Comment: Yes. It would be good to have runnable command in the official answer. Also, how do I do this using gcloud authenticated user (that was set up during `gcloud init`) rather than with a service-user json credentials file?

Comment: Howdy Joshua.  Ive updated the answer with our best so far command.  If we imagine that we need some credentials in order to make the call ... we should think about the concept of "Application Default Credentials".  When you set the environment variable, you were setting some explicit credentials.  However, if you are running in CLoud Shell or a GCP Compute Engine, you have implicit credentials.

Comment: Thank you. I edited some typos in that string. I'd like to just run it as I run `gcloud` , on my dev machine, with no JSON file, but perhaps I'll ask that as a separate question

Comment: On how to avoid downloading a JSON from the Cloud Console, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59764257

Comment: Using `gcloud auth print-access-token` as the authentication command will avoid the need to download a separate JSON file

Comment: There's a gcloud command that uses this API now: 

`ORG_ID="$(gcloud projects get-ancestors $PROJECT_ID | grep organization | cut -f1 -d' ')"`

Comment: Amazingly, `gcloud projects get-ancestors` (as of gcloud CLI version 428.0.0) doesn't accept the `--filter` argument like most other `gcloud` commands do. So, it seems we have to use command pipes (e.g., `grep`, `jq`, etc.) to massage the data as illustrated by @KarlKFI rather than using `gcloud ... --filter=...`